# tkinter get() fails to return user input2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Whenever I am to attempt to use the information from an Entry box, an output such as ".56424824" is the result.

```
def MainLogin(Username,Password):
    file = open("UserLogins.txt","r")
    file_reader = csv.reader(file)
    user_find(file_reader,Username)
    file.close()
def user_find(file,strUsername):
    for row in file:
        if row[0] == strUsername:
            print("Username found: " +strUsername)
            user_found = [row[0],row[1]]
            print(user_found)
            pass_checker(user_found)
            break
        else:
            print(strUsername)
            print(row[0])
            print("Not found")        
def pass_checker(user_found,strPassword):
    if user_found[1] == strPassword:
        print("pass match")
    else:
        print("pass Invalid")


def login():
    global toDestroy
    Login = Tk() # Create window.
    Login.geometry("1000x700+300+0") # Change size and position of window.
    Login.title("Login_Screen") # Give window a name.
    Login.config(bg="white")
    toDestroy.destroy()
    toDestroy = Login


    Title = Label(Login, text='Login Screen')
    Title.configure(font="Helvetica 12 bold")
    Title.grid(column=0, row=1)

    giveUsername= Label(Login, text='Username:')
    giveUsername.grid(column=0,row=2)
    Username= Entry(Login)
    Username.grid(column=1,row=2)


    givePassword= Label(Login, text='Password:')
    givePassword.grid(column=0,row=3)
    Password= Entry(Login, show='*')
    Password.grid(column=1,row=3)

    strUsername= Username.get()
    strPassword= Password.get()


    Submit= Button(Login,text='Submit.', command=lambda:MainLogin(Username,Password))
    Submit.grid(column=1,row=4,sticky='e')
    Submit.bind('<Return>',exe)

    backButton = Button(Login, text="Back To Main Menu.", command=lambda:toMenu(toDestroy))
    backButton.grid(column=0, row=0)

    createButton = Button(Login, text="Create a new user", command=create)
    createButton.grid(column=0,row=4, sticky='w')
    return toDestroy
    return strUsername
    return strPassword
```

Comment: That is because you define your entry fields in the same function you use `get()`. That will mean that `strUsername` and `strPassword` will always be an empty string. Looking at your code it appears that you don't quite get a GUI mainloop works. You need to only call `get()` at the instance you need the data and not at the same time your entry fields are created.

Comment: Use the solution recommended by @Mike-SMT. I also recommend that.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have tried using it in other functions, but whenever I had it came up with an issue where it would state that get was not applicable to strings. I'd really appreciate some clarification here, I've looked everywhere, but all solutions are hardcoded for logins for the most part.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks for the comments they were really useful. Especially the one referring to main loops and seperate functions.